# javascript/jquery toggle an element for each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I do a for loop in javascript to get the title and description for each item in my json file.

```
for (var i = 0, len = mydata.texts.length; i < len; i++) {
    list +="<li>"+"<div class='circle'></div>" + 
         "<span onclick='toggleDesc()'>"+ mydata.texts[i]["keyword"] +
         "</span>"+
        +"</li>"+
        "<div id='descr'>"+mydata.texts[i]["description"]+"</div>";    
}


function toggleDesc() {
    var x = document.getElementById('descr');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The result is like:

```
1. Title1
   description1
2. title2
   description2
3. Title3
   Description3
...
```

**Currently:**
 it is only toggling the first list item.

### question

How can I fix it to show each list item's description on click?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Currently:**
>   it is only toggling the first list item.

Because you can't use the same `id` with multiple elements in a page as it must be unique, and if you use it only the first one will be parsed with `document.getElementById()` so that's why only the first one is toggled.

**Solution:**

Use a `class` instead of an `id` so you can attach the event to all the elements having this class.

And in your HTML code pass a reference to the clicked `span` with `this` to your `toggleDescription()` function and use it to find the relevant `description` inside it.

This is how should be your code:

```
for (var i = 0, len = mydata.texts.length; i < len; i++) {
    list +="<li>"+"<div class='circle'></div>" + 
         "<span onclick='toggleDesc(this)'>"+ mydata.texts[i]["keyword"] +
         "</span>"+
         "<div class='descr'>"+mydata.texts[i]["description"]+"</div>"; 
        +"</li>"
}


function toggleDesc(item) {
    $(item).next('.descr').toggle();
}
```

And make sure you place the `description` div inside the `li` elemnt, because a list can contain only `li` as direct children.

### edit:

it needs a css specification to hide by default:

```
.descr{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: it has a reverse effect: it is showing the descriptions by default, and when clicked they disappear. they should be hidden by default. how could you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple elements with id `descr`. ids should be unique. Consider doing something this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = mydata.texts.length; i < len; i++) {
    list +="<li>"+"<div class='circle'></div>" + 
         "<span onclick='toggleDesc(" + i + ")'>"+ mydata.texts[i]["keyword"] +
         "</span>"+
        "<div id='descr" + i + "'>"+mydata.texts[i]["description"]+"</div>"
        +"</li>";
```

;
    }

```
function toggleDesc(i) {
    var x = document.getElementById('descr' + i);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: It will still render invalid HTML as `<ul>`/`<ol>` can only have `<LI>` as child

Comment: @Satpal I see. That's not a huge problem though, just rearrange the HTML so the `div` is inside the `li.`

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers in HTML must be **unique**. However you can use CSS class with multiple time which can be targeted by using Class Selector `.class`.

```
for (var i = 0, len = mydata.texts.length; i < len; i++) {
    list +="<li>"+"<div class='circle'></div>" + 
         "<span class='toggleDesc'>"+ mydata.texts[i]["keyword"] +
         "</span>"+
         "<div class='descr'>"+mydata.texts[i]["description"]+"</div>" +   
         "</li>";           
}
```

Note: I have placed *descr* as sibling of `SPAN` as `<ul>`/`<ol>` can only have `LI` as child

Also I would recommend, unobtrusive event handlers instead of using ugly inline event handlers.

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggleDesc', function(){
    $(this).next('.descr').toggle();
});
```

References [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach for dynamically generated elements. And In place of `document` you should use closest static container for better performance.

Comment: it has a reverse effect: it is showing the descriptions by default, and when clicked they disappear. they should be hidden by default. how could you fix this?

Comment: @jacky add css rule with the class or use `style="display:none"`